# Alternatives on using dictionary in python?

Tags: python

I have a text file with such format where:

```
SA:MC:1:1
UR:SA:0:0
KR:GE:2:0
AR:KR:1:0
```

and my code calculates the number of occurrence of the team name in the text file giving me an output as such:

```
SA: 2
MC: 1
UR: 1
KR: 2
AR: 1
```

code:

```
fileName = input("Enter the name of file:")
game = open(fileName)
table = []

for line in game:
contents = line.strip().split(':')
table.append(contents[:-2])

dictionary = {}
for line in table:
    for country in line:
        if country in dictionary:
            dictionary[country] += 1
        else:
            dictionary[country] = 1

for country, occurences in dictionary.items():
    print(country, ':', occurrences)
```

The code works and giving me the output desired since i looked into the dictionary term where it makes it easier for this kind of task. However, I'm wondering if there are any alternatives rather than using dictionaries? More of a **manual way** of doing it for **starters**?

Comment: Not really. Why would you want a more “manual way”?

Comment: The Pythonic way of doing key-value stores is using dictionaries. Do you have a good reason not to use them or are you only asking out of curiosity?

Comment: You could roll out your own [Red-black tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-black_tree) implementation and build a key-value store on top of that, but it would probably be slower than using dicts anyway.

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking. Bolding 'more manual' and 'for starters' is hardly an explanation

Comment: You could write it in C

Comment: @Pedro Castilho you could say I'm asking out of curiosity. Because for us starters learning python, i could say I've never stumbled upon dictionaries that is in my syllable just yet.

Comment: @Electric dictionaries are important in real-life Python coding. You should get used to them. You'll see them everywhere. There is no "more manual" way, don't worry if you're coming from a lower-level language.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it a *less* manual way using `collections.Counter`.

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter()

with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        a, b, _, _ = line.split(":")
        c += Counter([a, b])
```

But do note that a `collections.Counter` is just a special instance of a dictionary that's particularly good at counting things. Using key-value pairs is exactly how you'd solve this problem. Any other solution is contrived and silly.